# Implementing standard deviation classification in QGIS symbology?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is it possible to implement Standard deviation classification in QGIS symbology of a layer like in ArcGIS Desktop?

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Standard_deviation

I need to show values above and below the mean.

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS 2.4 there is a Standard Deviation mode in symbology like on the picture below:

[image: StdDev]

You have to choose the attribute column of the data to be presented, the number of classes you wish to have and the colour ramp with two different colours. You can also define custom intervals if you would like to, just be sure that you edit the labels too, so they will reference the updated value intervals (they won't update interactively).

**UPDATE:**

Standard Deviation mode makes equal intervals from the input data's distance from the average value. If you use an input column which has enough data below the mean to make more then one category, it will. Otherwise you can't change this mode's behaviour in creating the intervals.

[image: StdDev below mean]

Comment: Yes, but how can I display values above and below the mean. Like that in the example:[http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Standard_deviation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Standard_deviation)

Comment: Updated my answer to show you the easy way. If your data won't allow you to use this function, then you must go @SS_Rebelious's way.

Comment: @GaborFarkas Absolutely beautiful screenshots!

Answer (score 2):

You should install [R](http://cran.r-project.org/) and enable R support in *Processing Toolbox* settings. In R branch of scripts find *Basic Statistics -> Summary statistics* and execute it for the attribute you are working with.

[image]

You will get the mean value and the standard deviation in the output among the other data.

Then using field calculator create a new attribute and fill it with difference between values and the mean devided by standard deviation: `("field_name" - mean_value) / standard_daviation`, e.g: `("values" - 15) / 1.2`. Then just make a classification of the resulting field - the standard deviation from the mean that will have positive and negative values.