# Creating Standard Deviation Index (SDI) cell by cell in DEM

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, qgis-processing

I am fairly new to QGIS and have been struggling to find a solution. To put it simply I am trying to find a way to display the Standard Deviation Index on individual cell basis by comparing it to its surrounding 8 cells. The purpose is to help narrow down possible habitat of a bird species. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful for you:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115397/81215

But it is also possible to convert the DEM to points,
and then use a formula in the [Field Calculator] tool (without using [R])

```
(round("ELEV") - mean(  round("ELEV") )) /  stdev(round("ELEV") )
```

this will give an overall relative standard deviation value.

to get specific stats on different cell sizes there are several algorithms to try in [raster analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#cell-statistics.)